# printer in pdp-11

Tags: assembly, pdp-11

I have this snippet of the code. can somebody explain why It doesn't work, I want every 5 seconds print "Syntax Error"

thanks in advance

```
tks = 177560
tkb = 177562
tps = 177564
tpb = 177566
lcs = 177546
. = torg + 2000

main:   mov #main, sp

 mov #outp, @#64
 mov #200, @#66

        mov #clock, @#100
        mov #300, @#102

 mov #101, @#tks
 mov #100, @#tps
 mov #100, @#lcs

prog:   mov #msg, -(sp)
 br outp


clock:  inc time_is
 cmp time_is, time_out
 bne clk_end
 clr time_is
 jmp prog
clk_end:rti


outp:   
 mov r1,-(sp)
        mov r2,-(sp)
        mov 6(sp),r2
str_loop:
        movb (r2)+,r1
        beq pr_str_end
        jsr pc, print_char
        br str_loop
pr_str_end:
        mov (sp)+,r2
        mov (sp)+,r1
        rts pc

print_char: 
        tstb @#tps
        bpl print_char
        movb r1, @#tpb
        rts pc

. = torg + 3000
msg:.ascii<Syntax Error>
    .byte 0
    .even

time_out: .word 300
time_is: .word 0


buffer: .blkw 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discailmer: my knowledge of PDP-11 is a bit rusty, so make sure that this makes sense...

You have 2 problems in your code:

1. The `main` part calls `prog` which calls `outp`, when it should be simply looping endlessly so that `clock` will call the printing function. Try putting `mainloop: br mainloop` in the end of `main` (just before `prog`).
2. The way it's written right now, you're entering `outp` by branching, but exiting it with `rts pc`, which is wrong. `clock` sould call `prog` using `jsr prog`.

Another minor problem is that printing the message might take more than 5 second (who knows?) so you need to protect the `clock` method form calling `outp` again if it's not done.

Good luck.

Comment: Is there anyone who's knowledge of PDP-11 **isn't** rusty? If so, I pitty them!

Answer (score 1):

Looks the the string pointer on the stack is a 4(sp), not 6(sp).